# touchCornerSize does not exist in type 'IPolylineOptions'

Tags: canvas, fabricjs

I build an Angular App and I want to use touchCornerSize.

I have run `npm run build_with_gestures` successfully but when I add the property to a Polygon, I get

`touchCornerSize does not exist in type 'IPolylineOptions'`.

After installing the custom library, I have restarted the app and the editor.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The answer is simple.

The properties shown in the Docs are not options, but class variables.

This means that `touchCornerSize` is not added as an option when the object is initialized, but as a direct variable. E.g

```
this.polygon.touchCornerSize = 20;
```